# R - Error in `:=`(variable, as.character(variable))

Tags: r, data.table, colon-equals

I'm trying to run an R script, which can be found [here](https://github.com/TUD-OS/flogsim/blob/master/script/plot_trace.R) with the command
 `plot_trace.R -m ./log.model.csv ./log.trace.csv`.

The two csv files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fWeF0CcjaHWwo6dzSrKf3a3v2S8IE57q?usp=sharing).

This produces the error:

```
Error in `:=`(variable, as.character(variable)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
Calls: [ -> [.tbl_df -> check_names_df -> :=
```

Last but not least my sessionInfo() output:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2414988) so that we can better help you? Also, did you try to run `is.data.table` on the variable that causes the error?

Comment: is.data.table(trace.df) evaluates to false. Does that mean, that the trace data I read in, is in the wrong format somehow?
A minimal reproducible example would include compiling the whole project and then there is still no guarantee that the error will be reproduced, since the maintainer of the repo doesn't experience the same the problems that I have.

Comment: A minimal reproductible example would include a sample of your data that can recreate the error, along with the exact part of the code that produces it (I think we may have already guessed the line that causes the error). See the link I shared. Without it, all we can do is tell you that you are trying to use `data.table` methods on an object that isn't a `data.table`, thus the error.

Comment: I updated my post. I'd be grateful, if you had another look.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to run this script with the data you provided. However, I didn't have any error. Here's the command I used: `Rscript --vanilla plot_trace.R -m ./log.model.csv ./log.trace.csv`. Can you try to run the script step by step, for example from RStudio, to see where the problem arises and to check the class of `trace.df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I found two problems with this script:

- The author mixes functions from `tidyr` and variables of class `data.table`. These functions will likely return data frames and using `data.table` syntax on these will cause errors. Unfortunately, some `tidyr` functions may return `data.table` when operating on one, but this seems to vary greatly depending on the version of the `tidyr` package.
- The `unnest` function from `tidyr` has a new interface. The script won't work as is with `tidyr` version 1.0.0 or later.

Below are the lines I changed to fix the script, using R version 3.6.1 and `tidyr` version 1.0.0:

- *line 56:* added `trace.df <- as.data.table(trace.df)`
- *line 64:* changed to `trace.df <- unnest(trace.df, cols)`
- *line 65:* added `trace.df <- as.data.table(trace.df)`

**Original answer**

I was able to run the script on the data you provided without error. Both

```
Rscript --vanilla plot_trace.R -m ./log.model.csv ./log.trace.csv
```

and

```
chmod +x plot_trace.R
./plot_trace.R -m ./log.model.csv ./log.trace.csv
```

produced the following plot:

[image: Result plot]

Can you run the script step by step in RStudio to check the class of `trace.df` after each step?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, after upgrading to 3.6.1 the error still persists. Running `Rscript --vanilla plot_trace.R -m ./log.model.csv ./log.trace.csv` gives me:   `Error in strsplit(x, "\\|") : non-character argument
Calls: [ ... [.data.table -> eval -> eval -> lapply -> FUN -> strsplit
Execution halted`

Comment: @Moostropfen: The error doesn't persist, it's a new one, caused by the call to `strsplit` on line 62. It seems like the problem with `data.table` was indeed fixed by upgrading to R 3.6.1. Check `trace.df` for non-character values in the columns `value` and `field`, in particular missing values.

Comment: Forget what I wrote. I messed a few things up... I added `trace.df <- as.data.table(trace.df)` as recommended. That gives me `unnest() has a new interface. See ?unnest for details.
Try df %>% unnest(c(value, field)), with mutate() if needed 
Error in :=(CPU, as.integer(CPU)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and :=(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
Calls: [ -> [.tbl_df -> check_names_df -> :=
Execution halted`. When I remove it, I get the same error message from the beginning.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution. I wasn't using `tidyr` version 1.0.0 while you were, so I wasn't getting the error from the new interface of `unnest`. This new solution should fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `unnest` call is creating something that is not a data table.

At line 56 try adding:

```
trace.df <- as.data.table(trace.df)
```

Comment: Calling `unnest` on a `data.table` returns a `data.table`. Try running the examples from `unnest` documentation with a `data.table` instead of a data frame.

Comment: After checking, this is only true for R version 3.6 and later, my bad!